# Java's application in container. TRACE logs level enable from console

Tags: java, docker, logging, trace

In my app, I'm using **slf4j** java logger.

```
       <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Which has a configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ERRORS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
        <file>/logs/errors.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>errors%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.company" level="DEBUG"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Example code

```
public class SomeClass {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(SomeClass.class);
    
  private void process() {
        LOGGER.trace("Processing...");
        if (!Strings.isEmpty("empty")) {
            LOGGER.debug("not empty");
            LOGGER.info("not empty");
            LOGGER.error("not empty");
            LOGGER.warn("not empty");
            execute("action");
        }
    }
}
```

I trying find some way to show TRACE log level, but on runing container. Actualy if I want to show logs a just type.

```
docker logs -f  [container-name] --tail 500
```

Then I can see **INFO, ERROR, WARN, DEBUG** levels without TRACE

I'm wondering if exist some tools or command to show TRACE level also ? For example.

```
docker logs -f  [container-name] --tail 500 | cmdTraceLevelTool
```

****I know how to enable TRACE level, using logback-spring.xml or application.properties file**** but all knowing me ways enable it permamently and they have in coded. I'm looking something from console, in runtime, on working application.
I want to have a choice, all or wihout TRACE. It is possible ?

Comment: If your application supports JMX you should be able to send a command to your application and can alter the debug-level that way. I.e. if you have a spring-boot application and utilize spring-boot-admin there is a fairly easy way, once the security configuration is done properly, to change the log-level produced via the Web interface of the spring-boot-admin. This should give you enough pointers to do further research

Answer (score 1):

No the application is responsible for writting the log file. So you have to inform the application to also append TRACE logs. Docker can not do that with a command for you. Docker controls what the container does and how it executes. It can not control how the application running inside the container works.

Most close to what you want from what I can think of, is the following. Enable `TRACE` logs in logback-spring.xml and then use the following command to read only specific logs in console.

```
docker logs -f  [container-name] --tail 500 | grep 'TRACE'
```

It will filter from all logs all lines that include the word `TRACE`.

Comment: Thx. For answer and specific information. I know this way with grep, but this is still no resolve my problem. Hmmm I wondering it is whole possible, reading your post. May be someone will be find something for me.

Comment: @Mbded Once the application starts, it reads the file logback.xml and follows those rules while the application runs. Docker can not interrupt the application. It's an application thing. Docker just provides the environment where the application runs. Even if you modify logback.xml the application must be restarted again. Nothing on docker. It's how the application works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use environment variable.

1. Configure your log level to this EV and make it INFO as default value.
2. Add the EV to your dockerfile and passe it to CMD (java -jar ...).
3. run your docker container with this EV (-e YOUR_EV=TRACE).

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! Would be helpful if you could add some code to your answer!